# how to apply background color to the found text

Tags: jquery

hello i have following code and it works fine for finding and replacing string... but it is not working globally..how to make it to work as globally and after replacing i want to highlight that string into green color.. how..?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#replace').click(function(){
var oldstr=$('#inputstring').val();
var newstr=$('#newstring').val();
var para=$('#para').html();
var result=$('p:contains('+oldstr+')');


if(result)
{
var x=para.replace(new RegExp(oldstr, 'i','g'), newstr);
$('#para').empty().html(x);

}
})
})
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  Enter the string to find:<input type="text" id="inputstring"><br>
  Enter string to replace:<input type="text" id="newstring"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Replace" id="replace"><br>
  <p id="para">This is the new paragraph written to test how to replace the a string  with desired string</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(oldstr, '<span style="color: green">' + newstr + '</span>'));
```

Comment: ok it is fine for changing the color.. but to find a string globally and replace all at a time what to do...

Comment: @Mihir: that's what this does - replaces every occurrence of `oldstr` in the body of the page. Isn't that what you mean by 'globally'? Beware, though, that this basically recreates the whole page - so all your event handlers and jquery data will get blown away.

Comment: @sje397 , is this not expensive line of code ?? i am not saying its bad or somthing, just asking like that

Comment: @sej.. thank you.. but is it possible to find using regular expressions for global check.. here i have RegEx(olstr,'i','g'). it is not working.. is there any way to make it work..

Comment: @gov - yeah, depending on the size of the page, it could be expensive. I'm not sure how to do it more cheaply though.

Comment: @Mihir: I think you should just be able to replace `oldstr` with `RegEx(oldstr, 'i', 'g')` in the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need to do:

```
if(result){
     var x=para.replace(new RegExp(oldstr, 'i','g'), newstr);
     $('#para').empty().html(x);
     $('#para').html($('#para').html().replace(oldstr, '<mark>' + newstr + '</mark>'));
}
```